# Archive files in a NAS storage

Tags: windows, storage, scheduler, robocopy, nas

I want to archive some files in a NAS storage. I have the path, the directory contains thousands of files, i want to move them to another folder in the same NAS storage and run a scheduler to archive files every week. How can I do that ?

I tried a POC using robocopy and task scheduler in windows, but I want the same thing in the NAS storage and I am lost

Comment: I think the right solution is based on installed NAS utilities. I recommend you to search for answer on apropriate site: [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).